# Is there a way to download all .txt files from the page via curl or wget command

Tags: macos, http, wget, curl

My question is in a title: Is there a way to download all .txt files from the page via curl or wget command? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use wget with `-A` to specify a type of file and `-r`to be recursive:

```
wget -r -A '*.txt' http://url-to-webpage-with-txts/
```

Comment: I've tried this corrected one, but just got index.html

Comment: I've tested on Linux Debian using bash. Is it possible that the txt files are behind an user/password authentication on the website?

Comment: No, it is possible to wget each file separately,here is link: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/21function/

Comment: I tried and only downloaded robots.txt. Are you sure that there are .txt files on that server?

Comment: Oh, my bad, this link : http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/21function/

Comment: This is link to the same page, its okay, I'll download it manually, thanks for your help!:)

Comment: I tried and it downloaded 10 txt files that were saved to the directory introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/21function

Comment: I'm using debian/bash and i understand that you're using OSX. try using double-quotes instead of single-quotes.

Comment: Oh, thanks, the problem was about single-quotes, just that, thanks!